# Which Prometheus functions should i use for setting an alert in Grafana on the ratio between total requests and successful requests?

Tags: twilio, prometheus, grafana, grafana-alerts

I'm using Twilio for sending MFA SMS for users login.

When i'm asking from Twilio to send SMS for me, i also deliver it a callback-url, which Twilio will POST it when the status of the message had been changed. In that callback endpoint, im incrementing a Prometheus counter, with status label (`message-status`).
Possible statuses are: queued, sent, delivered, failed and undelivered, while the "Healthy" statuses transition is queued-->sent-->delivered.

In addition, every time i'm getting a request to send an SMS, i'm incrementing another simple prometheus counter, with no labels at all (`total-messages`).

I queried these counters in Grafana:

```
sum(increase(message-status{status="delivered"}[1h]))

sum(increase(total_messages[1h]))
```

I tried to set an alert on the ratio between all the delivered messages and the total number of messages sent:

```
sum(increase(twilio_messages_status{status="delivered"}[1h])) / sum(increase(twilio_total_messages[1h]))
```

I made some manual testing, and the graphs didn't look as expected; while all the messages I sent was delivered successfully, I would expect that the ratio between those 2 metrics will be 1, but it isn't - the counter (`total-messages`) was higher.

Now, I know for sure that all the messages were actually delivered:

1. Looking at the dashboard at my Twilio account
2. Looking at the logs of the pod (which prints log every time one of these counters is incremented)
3. The messages was targeted to my private phone, and iv'e got them all.

I guess the way i queried the metrics is wrong:
I tried to remove the 'increase' function, and stay with sum function only. Then, i saw that both graphs are identical, as expected!!

So how is it possible that when i'm using increase i'm not seeing exactly the same graphs?
What am i doing wrong?
Which Prometheus functions should i use for cases like this?
Is there more convenient way to set an alert on these kind of metrics (total requests against successful requests)?

Thank you!